# ASP.Net page flow

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I new to using ASP.net-mvc and would like some help.  I created a web application using VS2010 and need to change the way the pages flow.  How do I code it so that the first page the user is presented is not the home page but the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You modify the default route in Global.asax in the RegisterRoutes method.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "LogOn", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your route (in global.asax.cs) defaults - from controller "home" and action "index", to what you need.

And more importantly you need to read some tutorials and books on technology your are new on, before asking basic questions on SO.

Answer (score -1):

From [Stephen Walther's page](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-17-how-to-run-an-asp-net-mvc-application.aspx):

> Specific Page – Enables you to set a particular page to run. You can set the page here or you can right-click a page in the Solution Explorer window and select the menu option Set As Start Page.

I have not tried this with mvc 3 app however.

Comment: we can tell you havent, because there is no such thing in asp.net MVC as start page... -1